# could I validate user auto-renew subscription directly inside the app? or my App would be rejected?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, subscriptions, auto-renewing

The server code to validate a receipt its very simple, so could I validate the subscription directly on my app? or I must implement it in some server in order to not get an Apple rejection?

and if my application have videos that are added every month, that kind of content might cause an app rejection to?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know that Apple will reject for validating on the device (I don't think so) but people will use it as a security weakness to crack your purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to validate on a separate server. you can validate directly with the apple server. it is however not recommended. i have several apps that validate directly with the apple server (all accepted) because my client does not want to deal with the verification on their end.

Comment: all I wanted to know, Thanks Joris Weimar!

Comment: what might be an issue however is using auto-renewable subscriptions. they have quite specific criteria. your app will likely be rejected if you don't meet them...